# Magento2 admin panel ordered product link

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, admin-panel, order-grid

How to add products link in magento2 sales=> order tab in admin panel?
Also I want to add custom attribute to order grid in admin panel. for example want to add type(custom attribute) to admin panel sales=> order grid

More description: Login to admin panel, go to sales: order, open one of orders, you can see ordered items. I want to have item links and view products who ordered

also want to add one column in ordered items. want to show custom attribute like type or model in ordered items info

Comment: Please describe your question in detail, if possible with a screenshot.

Comment: @AshokDubariya Updated. thanks for your response

Answer (score 3):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

Introduced new `custom_column` and changed `column_name` block's template for product name with url

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">custom column</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-customcolumn</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Vendor_Module::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn"
                   name="column_custom_column"
                   template="Vendor_Module::items/column/custom_column.phtml" group="column" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * @see \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name
 */
?>

<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
         <!-- added product url -->
        <a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>" target="_blank"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
    </div>

    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('SKU') ?>:</span> <?= implode('<br />', $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['label'] ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['value'] ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid() ?>"> ...</span><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id = 'id' . uniqid() ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                            <script>
                                require(['prototype'], function() {
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').show();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').show();});
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/custom_column.phtml

you can get product attributes from here

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $block->getItem()->getProduct();
```

Comment: Use:
`<a target="_blank" href="<?= $block->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', ['id'=>$block->getItem()->getProduct()->getId()]) ?>">View Product</a>`
To add link to admin product page.

Answer (score 0):

@Ranganathan
Would it be possible to make the url point to the backend url

```
<a href="<backend_product_url>" target="_blank"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
```